# Performance benchmark for API frameworks written in different languages

Tags: performance, api, benchmarking, performance-testing, backend

I'm building a REST API and I want to know if anyone has compiled a list of performance benchmarks in all or most of the following languages:

- Node
- Ruby
- Python
- Go

I'm most familiar with the node frameworks (hapi, express, restify), but I'm curious about the others for contention's sake.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A really popular web application benchmark is: https://www.techempower.com/benchmarks/#section=data-r10&hw=peak&test=json

But you may roll your own to map more closely your needs using any of the following tools:

- [wrk](https://github.com/wg/wrk)
- [jmeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/)
- [tsung](http://tsung.erlang-projects.org/)
- [vegeta](https://github.com/tsenart/vegeta)
- [http_load](http://www.acme.com/software/http_load/)
- [siege](http://freecode.com/projects/siege)
- [thor](https://github.com/observing/thor)

Comment: You can add Tsung and locust to the list above :)

Comment: @raziehbabaee Updated :-)